# "I did want to" versus "I wanted to"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

When is it correct to use the form "I did want to ..." versus "I wanted to..." (substitute other verb for "want"). I often find myself changing from the former to the latter when I edit early drafts, but sometimes the former seems to better emphasize my "wanting".

EDIT: Part of my curiosity was that this has the feel of a slightly different tense, but it is not. The discussions in the following, which I found rather indirectly via the ELL meta site, are more what I was looking for. [Difference between "did + verb" and just "verb+ed"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118683/difference-between-did-verb-and-just-verbed)

Comment: I would suggest that it's just for emphasis. However note that in the negative, "did" is always used. "I didn't want to". To add emphasis, I would remove the contraction: "I did not want to go"

Comment: Instead of 'want' you can use the word 'desire'. 'I did desire to' or I desired to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I wanted to do this* is the ordinary past tense. *I did want to do this* adds emphasis to the verb.

Comment: Or adds emphasis to the past tenseness...I *did* want to do this, before I found out blah blah blah...